# Select2 Always show placeholder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I am using a select2 component for selection.

I fiddled an example together here:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/mmo2dqno/15/

What I am trying to do is:

- Select an item via the select2 widget
- Show that item in the div below
- Dont show the label in the search box.

This works fine. The problem is, that when one item is selected, the searchbox isn't showing the placeholder attribute anymore.

How can I tell the browser to assume the input as empty and show the placeholder again?

Answer (score 0):

You could kill the select2 plugin with JS, and then load it again.
Or you could use Js to choose an disabled placeholder option.